# How to use a numeric array constant array in MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

constant ex: `define('PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE',array('1,'2','3'));`

```
SELECT * from employee where id IN('PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE');
```

this above select is not working .

Comment: MySql in() operator does not accept array

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign an array to constant. Try doing it in this way:

```
define('PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE', json_encode(array('1','2','3')));

$sql = 'SELECT * from employee where id IN(' . implode(',', json_decode(PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE, true)) . ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a string, as you are using array right now

```
define("PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE","'1','2','3'");

echo 'SELECT * from employee where id IN ('.PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE.')';
```

I have checked it in this way

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP join function then write your query as below:-

```
$ids = join(',',[1,2,3]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

If you want to use array via constant then you should use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php),

```
define('PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE',serialize(array(1,2,3)));
$ids = join(',',unserialize(PERMANENT_EMPLOYEE)); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering .Its very strict i have to use constants please suggest a solution using constants